# Profile tab bar image pixelated when set programatically on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to set a profile image to the tab bar once downloaded from the user's db entry. To do so, I have to crop my image to 35x35 manually so that its not bigger than the bar using the following method:

```
func crop(to: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        guard let cgimage = self.cgImage else { return self }

        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)

        guard let newCgImage = contextImage.cgImage else { return self }

        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

        //Set to square
        var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
        var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
        let cropAspect: CGFloat = to.width / to.height

        var cropWidth: CGFloat = to.width
        var cropHeight: CGFloat = to.height

        if to.width > to.height { //Landscape
            cropWidth = contextSize.width
            cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
            posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
        } else if to.width < to.height { //Portrait
            cropHeight = contextSize.height
            cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
            posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
        } else { //Square
            if contextSize.width >= contextSize.height { //Square on landscape (or square)
                cropHeight = contextSize.height
                cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
                posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
            }else{ //Square on portrait
                cropWidth = contextSize.width
                cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
                posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
            }
        }

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight)

        // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
        guard let imageRef: CGImage = newCgImage.cropping(to: rect) else { return self}

        // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
        let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(to, false, self.scale)
        cropped.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: to.width, height: to.height))
        let resized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resized ?? self
    }
```

Called on my "setViewControllers" method in the tab bar like so:

```
func setViewControllers() {

//.......
    let profileImage: UIImage = (UserManager.current?.profileImage?.crop(to: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)).roundedImage ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_tab_bar_icon.png")).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)Ca

    let profileNavBarController = createViewController(identifier: "ProfileNavigationController", storyboardName: "Profile", tabBarImage: profileImage)

    profileNavBarController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 9, left: 0, bottom: -9, right: 0)

    self.viewControllers = [foo, bar, profileNavBarController]
}
```

Obviously, this does not manage for retina as I cannot set a @2X and @3X version. Hence, the image turns out to be pixelated in the tab bar:

[image: Pixelated tab image]

I tried setting the image size to 70x70, which obviously returns an image that does not fit the tab bar. I also researched a way to create a UIImage object with @2X and @3X, but found nothing.

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: Have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624122-renderingmode?language=objc and try to use the property in your code. See what the property does. 

Also, check the human interface guidelines https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/ and search for `Tab Bar Icon Size` and see what you can apply to your case and solve the problem.

Comment: jacobo Did you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following extension to your project, you can add after the ViewController.swift class ends.

```
extension UITabBarController {
    
    func addSubviewToLastTabItem(_ imageName: String) {
        if let lastTabBarButton = self.tabBar.subviews.last, let tabItemImageView = lastTabBarButton.subviews.first {
            if let accountTabBarItem = self.tabBar.items?.last {
                accountTabBarItem.selectedImage = nil
                accountTabBarItem.image = nil
            }
            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.frame = tabItemImageView.frame
            imgView.layer.cornerRadius = tabItemImageView.frame.height/2
            imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.clipsToBounds = true
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            self.tabBar.subviews.last?.addSubview(imgView)
        }
    }
}
```

Now open ViewController.swift file add the following method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.tabBarController?.addSubviewToLastTabItem("profile")
}
```

[Reference Guide](https://iosrevisited.blogspot.com/2019/08/add-imageview-profile-picture-to-tabbar-swift-ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue This one Worked!

```
extension UIImage {

    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }

}
```

This is how to use it.

```
let profileImage: UIImage = (UserManager.current?.profileImage?..resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: 33, height: 33)).roundedImage ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_tab_bar_icon.png")).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

***consider removing `.roundedImage` if it didint worked***